# Linked server from Azure managed instance

Tags: linked-server, azure, azure-sql-managed-instance

I have my Managed Instance (**MI**) setup and can connect from SSMS on-premises. There is limited functionality this way (you only see databases and security) - so I have a VM in the v-net where I can manage the MI from.

I have set up a linked server from one of our servers to the MI fine - I can query the MI from the server using 4 part naming convention.

How do I do it the other way? Using the management jump-box with SSMS on I have the option to create the linked server, but I cant connect to the on-premise  server.

Comment: Try connecting to a SQL Server instance on a Jump Box on your Managed Instance's VNet.  Then ensure you can connect from the Jomp Box VM to your on-prem server.

Comment: I cant connect from jumpbox to on prem in SSMS

Comment: Then you won't be able to create a linked server from MI to on-prem.  To make this work your MI VNet would need to be routed to your on-prem network over S2S VPN or ExpressRoute.

Comment: The VNet which the MI and jump box are in i connected to the network here - I can connect from my desktop straight to the azure instance, just not the other way around?

Comment: It's down to network troubleshooting.  You'll need to check the NSGs in Azure and your on-prem firewalls to see if you have ports blocked. And Test-NetConnection is your friend: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/test-netconnection?view=win10-ps